# NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator doesn't fail the protractor spec but it passes flawlessly

Tags: javascript, typescript, protractor, e2e-testing

This is an automation framework using page object model. I use the async/await approach over promises. I am using TS, compiling it to JS (protractor) and then executing the scripts.

Page Object:

```
 async addProjectDetails(): Promise<void> {

        expect(await this.currentStep.getText()).toBe("Records"); //There is  no element like this, which I know.
        await this.projectTitle.sendKeys("Project Feb 1");
        await this.projectDescription.sendKeys("Project Description");
}
```

Spec:

```
it('should create a project successfully', async () => {
        try {
            await dashboard.createNewProject();
            await dashboard.addProjectDetails();
}
```

The page loads and the element doesn't exist. I get the error:

```
NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By(xpath, //custom-expandable-title[@class='not-completed active']//span[@class='child-title'])
```

However instead of failing the spec passes. Shouldn't it fail. Isn't this a false positive?

Comment: Two comments: 
- If using async await I would say look at using https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/chai-as-promised/  
  
- Is it possible that `expect` has error handling and it catches the error? I do see it has functionality for expect(test).to.not.throw();

Answer (score 0):

Errors raised in `try` wouldn't affect final result, they will stop execution of try block and start execution of `catch` block. If you want test to behave like this you have to move call of `addProjectDetails` away of `try` block.

Comment: I removed the try block. I just want to ensure that the spec fails on exceptions like NoSuchElementError.

Comment: Did you try something like this?

let someElement = element(by.xpath('...path'));
expect(someElement.isPresent()).toBeFalsy();